# How to deterministically divide floats when there is a known deviation from IEEE 754?

Tags: math, floating-point, binary, shader, directx

DirectX 11 allows GPU manufacturers to deviate from the rounding behavior specified in the IEEE 754 standard. I cannot enable IEEE strictness, because I don't control the shader compilation process.

The standard requires float results which cannot be represented as a 32-bit float to be rounded to the nearest representable float. DirectX allows the result to be truncated (floored) instead. Unfortunately, it's up to the manufacturer to decide what behavior to implement and there are differences between AMD and Nvidia.

I've been able to track down the difference to a float division. Example:

```
34969.0 / 60516.0 = 0.5778472   (according to IEEE 754 and on an Nvidia GPU)
34969.0 / 60516.0 = 0.5778471   (on an AMD GPU)
```

The difference is the last bit of the significand due to different rounding behavior.

```
0.5778472 = 0  00100111110110111001011  01111110
0.5778471 = 0  00100111110110111001010  01111110
                                     ^
```

Is it possible to manually ensure/correct the result of such a division to be deterministic, independent of whether the result uses standard rounding or truncating? Losing some precision would not be a problem.

Setting the last bit to a fixed value fixes some cases, but not those where more bits are different. Extreme example:

```
60516 / 60516 = 1.0        = 0  00000000000000000000000  01111111   (IEEE 754, CPU, Nvidia)
60516 / 60516 = 0.99999994 = 0  11111111111111111111111  01111110   (AMD)
```

Comment: "ensure/correct the result of such a division to be deterministic" --> So rounding by any scheme is OK as long as it is consistent across C implementations?

Comment: One way would take the significant of both `float a,b` as integers `ia,ib`, scale `ia` by `1LL<<23` and _integer_ divide (then subtract expos) and reform the quotient, but that is a fair amount of work.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, rounding or other minor changes would be ok, as long as the final result is consistent between GPU vendors. I don't yet completely understand your suggestion, but why would this be a lot of work? A couple of bit operations and an int division seem relatively cheap, if this results in a good approximation.

Comment: How much work is also language dependent.   What code language?  (Do not have time now to code up a C solution.  Perhaps later.)  IAC, there is always corner cases to consider (NAN, Inf, div/0, signed 0.0, etc.)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica This is HLSL shader code, somewhat similar to C. I think the rounding behavior is the only relevant deviation from the standard. Div/0 should be consistent. I will give this a try, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: (FYI, truncation or flooring (which are different for negative numbers) are allowed by the IEEE 754 standard; they are the roundTowardZero and roundTowardNegative methods. A fully conforming IEEE-754 implementation should provide the four basic rounding methods: those two plus roundTiesToEven and roundTowardPositive.)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I was able to get deterministic results with this approach, thanks a lot. I found some more details here: https://bits.stephan-brumme.com/inverse.html

Comment: @EricPostpischil By "allowed" I assume you mean provided as a compiler option/alternative, right? If I'm not mistaken, the default would be roundTiesToEven. My problem was that there is no explicit default with DirectX and it's left up to the vendor. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/floating-point-rules